# My python method isn't working correctly, skipping items in a list (playfair cipher)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a method that takes a key and an alphabet and creates a playfair cipher box. For those of you that don't know what that is, It takes the key and puts it in a  5 x 5 grid of letters, spilling onto the next line if neccessary, and then adds the rest of the letters of the alphabet. Each letter is only supposed to appear in the box once. I'm trying to do this with a list with 5 internal lists, each with 5 items. the only problem is that where the method is supposed to skip letters, it isn't. Here is the method and the output, can anyone help me?

```
def makePlayFair(key, alpha):
box = []
#join the key and alphabet string so that you only have to itterate over one string
keyAlpha = ""
keyAlpha = keyAlpha.join([key, alpha])
ind = 0
for lines in range(5):
    line = []
    while len(line) < 5:
        if isIn(keyAlpha[ind], box) or isIn(keyAlpha[ind], line):
            print(isIn(keyAlpha[ind],box))
            ind += 1
            continue
        else:
            line.append(keyAlpha[ind])
            ind += 1
    box.append(line)
return box

def isIn(item, block):
    there = None
    for each_item in block:

        if type(each_item) == type([]):
            for nested_item in each_item:
                if item == nested_item:
                    there = True
                    break
                else:
                    there = False
        else:       
            if item == each_item:
                there = True
                break
            else:
                there = False
    return there

>>> makePlayFair("hello", alphabet) #alphabet is a string with all the letters in it

> `[['h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'a'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q'], ['r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v']]`
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

cheers, brad

Comment: I think you are missing the code that actually does something.

Comment: Could you please actually include your makePlayFair method code?  That would help.

Comment: oops, meant to attach the method but i copied the wrong text [facepalm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in isIn:

Your break statement only breaks out of the inner for loop. The code then continues to iterate over the second for loop. This means that only the last one is considered. You have to make sure that you exit out of both loops for this to work correctly.

The entire process can be made simpler by doing something like:

```
def makePlayFair(key, alpha):


    letters = []
    for letter in key + alpha:
        if letter not in letters:
            letters.append(letter)

    box = []
    for line_number in range(5):
        box.append( letters[line_number * 5: (line_number+1) * 5])
```

Comment: I thought about that but I'm not sure how you break out of both loops. Also If you run something like `code`isIn("a", [["b"], ["c"], ["a"]] it outputs true which is why I'm not really sure what to do

Comment: @shadesandcolour The easiest way to break out of both loops is to return True

Comment: @shadesandcolour, your example there works because only the last one ends up mattering.

Comment: I can't believe that it was that simple! I had tried the return statement but my syntax must have been off. Thanks for your help. This is kinda my learner project for python.

Answer (score 1):

Make the list of letters first, then break them up into the 5x5 grid:

```
def takeNatATime(n, seq):
    its = [iter(seq)]*n
    return zip(*its)

def makePlayfair(s):
    keystr = []
    for c in s + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        if c not in keystr:
            keystr.append(c)
    return list(takeNatATime(5, keystr))

print makePlayfair("hello")
```

Prints:

```
[('h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'a'), ('b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g'), ('i', 'j', 'k', 'm', 'n'), ('p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't'), ('u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from string import ascii_uppercase
import re

def boxify(key):
    cipher = [] 
    key = re.sub('[^A-Z]', '', key.upper())[:25]

    for i in range(max(25 - len(key), 0)):
            for letter in ascii_uppercase:
                if letter not in key:
                    key += letter
                    break

    for i in range(0, 25, 5):
        cipher.append(list(key[i:i+5]))

    return cipher


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print boxify("This is more than twenty-five letters, i'm afraid.")
    print boxify("But this isn't!")
```

Comment: Your first argument only contains 16 unique letters, so would still be a valid key. Only if you supplied a pangram would there be difficulty. (You should only clip to the first 25 letters *after* dropping duplicates.)

Comment: Ah yes! You're right, of course, and your solution above is also far more elegant. Cheers!